# Disabled textarea and input fields, make font more readable (instead blur)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css, fonts, disabled-input

In several of my mvc pages, I have  disable certain fields like textarea and input boxes with the "disabled" attribute that are uneditable fields. But users are complaining about the text/font being hard to read. It looks blurred and too light.

Anyone have recommendation to make diabled fields more readable?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use CSS style for that. I suggest you to use the :disabled selector.
As an example, you can do something like this to change the color for example :

```
input:disabled { color: #FF0000; background: #ccc; }
```

You can find a good tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).